# Jquery selector to get all inputs that has a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I hope you're having a nice day

I have a dynamic table like this:

[image]

I would like to know if is possible make a Jquery selector to get all the inputs that has a value something like this:

$('.some-input-class:valueNotEmpty')

And get a array that only has the inputs with values

Is this possible? or I have to make something like this:

```
$('.some-input-class').each(function(){
   if($(this).val()){
      //Do something
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no selector in jQuery to target form controls which have a value. However you can use `filter()` to achieve it instead:

```
let $inputs = $('.some-input-class').filter((i, el) => !!el.value.trim())
```

Working example:

```js
let $inputs = $('.some-input-class').filter((i, el) => !!el.value.trim())
$inputs.addClass('valid');
```

```css
.some-input-class {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.valid {
   border: 2px solid #0C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="foo" class="some-input-class" />
<input type="text" value="bar" class="some-input-class" />
<input type="text" value="" class="some-input-class" />
<input type="text" class="some-input-class" />

<select class="some-input-class">
  <option value="">Please select...</option>
  <option value="lorem">Lorem ipsum</option>
</select>

<select class="some-input-class">
  <option value="">Please select...</option>
  <option value="lorem" selected>Lorem ipsum</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help @Rory

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `placeholder-shown` pseudo-class which is also supported almost by all modern browsers.

To get it working, you need to apply **placeholder** to all inputs in your HTML. But if you wish, you don't want it to be visible, you can do it like following:

```
<input type="text" placeholder=" " />
```

Now you can use the `placeholder-shown` pseudo-class to select all input fields with text.

```
$("input:not(:placeholder-shown)")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @enucar